# Image Upload Security - User Profile

Tags: image, security, upload, malware

we have to implement a feature user profile Image upload in our web application. the user can upload his profile image .

after uploading image it will be saved to DB2 DB .. and it will be rendered only to the user who uploaded the image after the login.
Technology stack -> J2EE , AIX, DB2.

we got a strange complaint from our security department that this feature needs to be dropped because the user may upload a virus and this will infect the server !

I don't understand how a user will upload the virus, at the end of the day the virus is a program that needs to be executed ,right?
second thing the platform is UNIX-AIX ,,, even if user uploaded a malware the server will not be infected , right ?
last thing, there is a possibility that user will be infected by XSS in case a JS file uploaded instead of image, but i can see that this in our case is not valid because only the user can upload the image and it will be rendered only to the user..

Is my understanding is right ?

Comment: what image upload are you using?

Answer (score 0):

No, it is actually possible to hide executable code in image files.
And when the user renders the image, it may be possible depending on the server configuration that the code inside the image can be executed.
See for example http://hackaday.com/2014/11/15/hiding-executable-javascript-in-images-that-pass-validation/
And search in google for gif executable, png executable, etc.

I have seen proofs of concepts that allow to run windows executables like this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9791/Hiding-EXE-Data-Within-GIF-Data, batch commands and other stuff for linux (even rm -fr *), php code and many others.

You will have to either verify the image or be sure the image is converted to a safe format before it gets rendered.

Comment: 1) it is user profile image, so i don't expect that user will upload and executable file to hurt his machine. because it will be rendered only for him. 2)the technology is j2ee not php, this will make a difference i think 3)you mentioned that we need to verify the image or be sure the image is converted to a safe format before it gets rendered, how to do that ?

Comment: 1. The file is not exactly created for the purpose of hurting his machine, the file can be for example to scale privileges or execute something on the server.


2. No, it makes no difference. java is also executed on the server side. Those are links that you can check to verify those things are possible with windows and javascript, but it doesn't mean that it cannot be used the same technique to achieve similar goals in unix/ruby/asp.net/java2ee/

3.Easiest way is to load an image library that already has that thing build in, or learn how to deal with the content of images and make a render.